# Issue with API CSV importer and activity imports

Tags: import, activity, csv

WP 6.03, CiviCRM 5.51.3, API CSV importer 1.1.  I'm attempting to import an activity via this extension since I need to include the assignee (which isn't included in the standard activity import).  The queue runner hangs each time without completing.

These are the fields I'm including: activity type (I've tried both the ID and the label), activity date, source contact (using contact ID), target contact (using contact ID), assignee contact (using contact ID), status, subject, priority.

Inspecting the log shows me this error:

$CRM_Queue_ErrorPolicy_reportError = Array
(
[is_error] => 1
[is_continue] => 0
[exception] => Error 1: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to civicrm_api4() must be of the type string, null given, called in /home/XXXX/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Import/Parser.php on line 1470 and defined in /home/XXXX/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/api/api.php:62

Stack trace:

#0 /home/XXXX/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Import/Parser.php(1470): civicrm_api4(NULL, 'getFields', Array)

#1 /home/XXXX/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Import/Parser.php(1408): CRM_Import_Parser->getFieldMetadata('source_contact_...', true)

#2 /home/XXXX/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Import/Parser.php(1364): CRM_Import_Parser->getFieldOptions('source_contact_...')

#3 /home/XXXX/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Import/Parser.php(1857): CRM_Import_Parser->getTransformedFieldValue('source_contact_...', '56186')

#4 /home/XXXX/www/www/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/extensions/nz.co.fuzion.csvimport/CRM/Csvimport/Import/ in /home/XXXX/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/api/api.php, line 62
[last_task_title] => Processed 1 rows out of 1
)

This would seem to suggest that I'm missing a required field but it's really difficult to tell, and of course there's no error guidance generated.  Any ideas where my problem lies?

Comment: and you definitely had your date format right? have you tested your csv (anonymised) on eg dmaster.demo.civicrm.org just to compare. you can add the ext' n via https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/extensions?reset=1&selectedChild=addnew

Comment: I tested multiple date formats, confirming each time that they matched - no luck.  However, I did _not_ test on the demo site; I'll do that next.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Testing on the demo site resulted in the same thing - no activity added, and no discernible error.  I also added the Log Viewer module and the log entries are as follows: [info] Running task: Processed 1 rows out of 1

Comment: may be time to open an Issue on the extension repo with steps how to replicate

Answer (score 0):

On 5.63 and 5.67 (dmaster) this works with the API CSV extension 1.12. May have been an issue on 1.1.

[image]